# Multiple ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django

I have something like that in models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
   name = CharField(max_length=150)
class B(models.Model):
    a= ForeignKey(A)
    name =  CharField(max_length=150)
```

and i created modelform for both
in views.py

```
def create(request):
     a_form = AForm()
     b_form = BForm()
     if request.method == 'POST':
          a_form = AForm(request.POST, prefix="a")
          b_form  = BForm(request.POST, prefix="b")
     if a_form.is_valid() and b_form.is_valid():
          a = a_form.save()
          b_form.cleaned_data["a"] = a
          b= b_form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/companies/detail/{b.id}')
     return render_to_response('companies/signup.html',{'AForm':a_form , 'BForm': b_form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and i got this error

```
Exception Value: mysite_b.a_id may not be NULL
```

Can anyone tell me what I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the prefix even in GET mode:

```
def create(request):
>>   a_form = AForm(prefix="a") 
>>   b_form = BForm(prefix="b")
     if request.method == 'POST':
          a_form = AForm(request.POST, prefix="a")
          b_form  = BForm(request.POST, prefix="b")
     if a_form.is_valid() and b_form.is_valid():
          a = a_form.save()
>>        b = b_form.save(commit=False)
>>        b.a = a
>>        b.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/companies/detail/{b.id}')
     return render_to_response('companies/signup.html',{'AForm':a_form , 'BForm': b_form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```